# Immutable data structures for 2d+ lattices

Tags: data-structures, matrices, cellular-automata, persistent-data-structure

I would like to find an immutable/persistent data structure that allows  efficient updating for 2d (or higher) lattices/arrays/matrices, and reasonable performance when appending in any direction. Updates would be typically be localized to certain areas.

I could probably make do with mapping a 1d vector onto 2 dimensions, but is there something better?

Background: I would like to implement a kind of cellular automaton where history is preserved to a degree.

Comment: When you say "appending in any direction", what do you mean? Adding a whole row or column?

Comment: Yes, appending or prepending columns and rows.

Comment: Are these "empty" rows, or do they have data in them already?

Comment: It would help this question if you did three things: 1. Describe what you already know, like "I can do this in log n time with red-black trees". 2. Describe what you want, like "I want log log n time". 3. Enumerate and describe precisely which operations you're interested in, like https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6455/an-efficient-data-structure-supporting-insert-delete-and-mostfrequent